# how can i use jqplot plugin json to graph vector serialize

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-templates, jqplot

Good afternoon everyone.
I have a `models.py` file with one of the other classes including a class like that.

```
class Reportage:
def get_num(self):
    end_date = self.date.end_date
    start_date = self.date.start_date
    duration = time.mktime(end_date.timetuple()) - time.mktime(start_date.timetuple())
    delta_t = duration / 60
    num = []

    for t in range(0,duration,delta_t):
        start = t + start_date
        end = datetime.timedelta(0,t+delta_t) + start_date
        n_num = self.get_num_in_interval(start,end)
        num.append([t, n_num])
    num_json=simplejson.dumps(num)
    return num_json
```

Now I want to use the plugin of `jqPlot` to put the array "num" on a graph.
the script that is suggested on the site http://www.jqplot.com is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
        // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
        // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
        var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
            var ret = null;
            $.ajax({
                // have to use synchronous here, else the function
                // will return before the data is fetched
                async: false,
                url: url,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data) {
                    ret = data;
                }
            });
            return ret;
        };

        // The url for our json data
        var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

        // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
        // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
        // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
        var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
            title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
            dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
            dataRendererOptions: {
                unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

How can I represent the vector "num" on the chart by using this script?
What should I change in the script?

Comment: How does the returned `JSON` looks like, are you sure it is correct? Otherwise the `jqPlot` bit looks OK.